# Can a DataGridView allow more than one "object" in a cell?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to allow more than one object in a cell in a `DataGridView`?

I want to display a Group in the first column and then in the column next to it I want to display all of the users that are in that group but in one cell (the cell next to the group name). And this can not be string manipulation because I need to be able to click on each of the users and drag and drop them around. I am using a `DataGridview` linked up to a SQL query database.

I am using Visual Basic with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this in the DataGridView.  You can, however, create a table that looks something like this:

```
GROUP   USER
------  -----

Group1  User1
Group1  User2
Group1  User3
Group2  UserA
Group2  UserB
```

Once you do this, then you can handle the `CellFormatting` event of the DataGridView and set the `e.FormattedValue` to `String.Empty` if the value of the cell above matches.  Then your table will "look" like:

```
GROUP   USER
------  -----

Group1  User1
        User2
        User3
Group2  UserA
        UserB
```

This is pretty much what you are looking for.  If you want the gridlines to go away, you can instead handle the DataGridView's `CellPainting` event to draw proper borders, center text, etc.

UPDATE:  Here's an example of using the CellFormatting event to hide the contents of a cell.  In this example, I am just using a List as my datasource, but you can substitute this for your SQL Data Source, DataTable, etc.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<GroupUserRow> _rows = new List<GroupUserRow>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _rows.Add(new GroupUserRow { Group = "Group1", User = "User1" });
        _rows.Add(new GroupUserRow { Group = "Group1", User = "User2" });
        _rows.Add(new GroupUserRow { Group = "Group1", User = "User3" });
        _rows.Add(new GroupUserRow { Group = "Group2", User = "UserA" });
        _rows.Add(new GroupUserRow { Group = "Group2", User = "UserB" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _rows;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            int prevRowIndex = e.RowIndex - 1;
            if (prevRowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1[0, prevRowIndex].Value == e.Value)
            {
                //this just "hides" the value from the screen, the value is not
                //removed from the cell
                e.Value = String.Empty;
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This cell's value is: " + dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
        }
    }

}

public class GroupUserRow
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I have done this earlier and what i did was i placed each group into an array and if the array contains the group already then the String = "" however the DGV repaints itself everytime I click on a cell. So if I click on a cell with a group name, it will then check to see if its in the array.. when it sees the groups is in the array it sets it to empty. So whenever I click on cells the string is set to empty. Any ideas? And any further explanation on CellPainting would be helpful! Thanks! =)

Comment: Hi James!  I added an example of using the CellFormatting event to hide cells.  Let me know how this goes! :-)

Comment: Hey Kevin! thanks for the quick responses!! This certainly helped alot!! Now one question that I have that I am worried I already know the anwser to is, If I have an entire row of cells that are set to String.Empty is there a way to just remove that row? I have been running into problems with the database complaining that after the row is deleted there is not enough space in the DGV for the SQL query. I ask mainly because it is not aesthetically appealing especially when i have over a 100 users. Also when it might get in the way of me adding dragDrop functionality. Thanks! =)